# Complete WF4 dynamic rules engine example

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have spent quite some time trying to learn WF4 (I'm a total n00b when it comes to WF), but I cannot seem to find any examples exactly what I’m trying to do:

I need to make a WF4 (C#) rule during runtime, save it to a database (currently SQL, but that’s not important to me), load the rule and execute it while still in runtime.

The two examples below indicate that this (loading and executing a rule made during runtime) should be possible:

http://www.nilzorblog.com/2011/11/using-wf4-as-rule-engine.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee960221(v=vs.100).aspx

I have got the two examples working independently without problems.

However, when I’ve tried combining the examples (which should be quite simple?) I constantly get loads of conversion errors like this:

*Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List < SharedLibrary.AssignmentRule > ' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List < ExternalRuleSetLibrary.RuleSetData > '*

I have searched far and wide for days for examples that does this right, but didn't find anything. This is why I'm asking the gurus here :) Thank you in advance!

**Can you provide an example or recipe of how to make a WF4 rule during runtime, save it to a database, load the rule and execute it while still in runtime?**

Comment: The question has been clarified - please reopen it, or at least tell me why you won't. :)

Comment: I'm getting really f'd off by moderators who close legitimate questions like this without any explanation.  I think it's about time Stackoverflow was replaced by something friendlier.

Comment: @ChrisJensen: Hello Chris, Just wanted to know what was your solution to the post. How do you make a WF4 rule execute during runtime?. Can we hide and show fields dynamically based on the outcome of the rule?

Comment: Sorry, but the project was dropped before I got that far. :-/